# How to Render images in shape/ polygon form?

Tags: c++, image, rendering, shapes, sfml

Hey i'm working with SFML right now, and upon finishing the tutorials i still do not know how to give a shape a texture or image, and not just a solid color/outline.

The only thing i know can take an image is a sprite, but thats WAY to simple, as it only allows you to render rectangular images in a rectangluar way!

**What are the tecniques for rendering images onto shapes, and ONLY inside the shape?** It would be great if some of you could provide some resources or SFML-specific stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFML has been updated since this question was originally answered and you can now add textures to shapes easily. The shape class has the `setTexture()` and `setTextureRect()` methods. `setTexture()` takes a pointer to an `sf::Texture`. See the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Shape.php).

```
Sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("mytexture.png"))
{
    std::cerr << "failed to load";
}
sf::RectangleShape myRect{ sf::Vector2f(width, height) };
myRect.setTexture(&texture);
myRect.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( x, y, width, height ));
```

Answer (score 1):

**2d:**

As far as I know, with SFML 1.6 it isn't possible to use a separate image as a mask. You can, however, use the alpha channel of an image to draw a "shape" from it. This is supported by default; just give your image an alpha channel.

[This post on the SFML forms](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=367&sid=a0ee04b5b5e7efbcee4b1935c5861a3c) verifies that using a separate image as a mask is not supported.

The author of SFML, Laurent Gomila, has posted some code that will allow you to mask using shapes, sprites, and strings. That can be found here: [Masking using Sprites, Shapes or Strings](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/SourceMaskingAlphaBlending). To get this working, however, you need to modify and recompile some parts of SFML.

**3d:**

With regards to using an image as a texture and mapping it to an object in 3d space, I don't think SFML has too much to help you with this besides setting up a window for you. There is a [project on Google Code called sf3d](http://code.google.com/p/sf3d/) that could maybe get you in the right direction, though.